# How to Insert tableview cells inside collectionview on tapping an item

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm having some difficulties with designing this type of screen.

[image]
[image]

This seems to be a collection view and when I click on it, it shows table view cells.
I tried a couple of ways, but they don't seems to be the right way.

1. Taking these tableview cells as collection view cells and inserting them.
2. Instead of taking it as collection view, I'm creating a tableview cell and showing 2 items in a single cell and creating multiple tableview sections to display all of them. For eg, if there are total 10 items, I will be creating 5 tableview sections and showing 5 tableview cells with 2 items in each one of them. And on a click, I will insert different tableview cells.

How should I make this design? A bit of code will be helpful.

Comment: You can also think of it as a UITableView on top of UICollectionView